# Why does changing stringsAsFactors in R change the file size?

Tags: r

I have pulled a set of data from a PostgreSQL database to work with it in R. While working on it, I was constantly being tripped up by having factors in some fields that I did not want as factors. So, I went back to the code that I used to pull the data, and ensured that `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` was set.

The original `.RData` file storing the pulled data (five tables, plus a variable storing the time that the data was extracted) was approximately 800MB. The updated version, where strings were not stored as factors, was over 2GB. Nothing changed within the database or within my code except for setting `stringsAsFactors` to false.

My initial suspicion was that the factor levels were more efficient for storing text, since the actual text would be stored once as the level, and then each value would just be assigned to a level. But I don't think that is right - my understanding is that factors in R *are* character data, with structure on top. So, in that case, I don't think there would be a meaningful difference in file size.

So, my question: why did changing `stringsAsFactors` from `TRUE` to `FALSE` change the size of the resulting data in such a large way?

Comment: short answer: factors are just integers with an extra attribute (labels) while the entire character string needs to be stored for every string

Comment: @rawr makes perfect sense but I'd never thought of that as a reason why `stringsAsFactors` is `TRUE` by default. thanks!

Comment: `factor`s in R are made for this exact purpose: to save memory when storing long string vectors that can have a small number of different values. Your initial suspicion was spot on.

Comment: This makes R factors sound like a SAS numeric variable that is formatted using PROC FORMAT - the underlying data is numbers, but strings are overlaid on top. Is there documentation anywhere that explains this?

Comment: To see this examine: `string<-rep(c("abc","def"),c(5,6)); fact<-factor(string); dput(string); dput(fact)`. Also, I suspect if you wrote both files to .csv, they'd be the same size.

Comment: See section `Value` of `?factor`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I also think in the olden times with S/R, categorical variables were much more common in data analysis than free text. of course now that is not really the case, hence the push to have the default changed which was subsequently denied by rcore

Comment: If someone puts the comments discussion into an answer, we can close and accept. Thanks...

Comment: @rawr Could you convert your comment into an anwer?

Comment: @TARehman see my previous comment; imo this question really deserves an answer; if rawr doesn't post an answer, you might consider posting a community wiki answer based on the comments

Comment: I will, if no one puts an answer. But thought I'd offer a chance first.

Comment: @nicola: It's no longer true that factors "save memory when storing long string vectors that can have a small number of different values". This was true until R started storing all strings in a global cache to avoid using excessive memory.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich But factors still save on storage space because of their structure?

Comment: In memory, no. On disk, yes.

Comment: @jaap Finally got around to this, how does that answer look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consolidating the comments from the question into an answer.

**Bottom line up front:** R factors are numeric vectors with attached labels, and they use character operations and comparisons. This is different from SAS, where categories are created by applying independent factors to numeric variables, and where numeric operations and comparisons are used.

Broadly, my initial suspicion about the factors being numeric values that are assigned to set text strings is correct. There are a few differences between how SAS and R handle this, which were the cause of my question.

In short, SAS allows you to create and apply custom formats to numeric data. So, if you have categorical data that is stored in a numeric variable (for instance, classifying races into numeric categories), you can keep that variable intact while displaying output using character strings.

Consider the SAS example:

```
DATA sample;
    INPUT id race;
    DATALINES;
    1 1
    2 1
    3 2
    4 3
    5 1
    6 2
    7 4
    8 3
    9 1
    ;
RUN;

PROC FORMAT;
    VALUE raceft 1 = 'White'
                 2 = 'Black'
                 3 = 'Asian'
                 4 = 'Other';
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=sample;
    FORMAT race raceft.;
RUN;
```

This outputs:

```
Obs    id    race
 1      1    White
 2      2    White
 3      3    Black
 4      4    Asian
 5      5    White
 6      6    Black
 7      7    Other
 8      8    Asian
 9      9    White
```

However, in this example, the variable `race` remains numeric. SAS operations against it use numeric categories and comparison operations. For instance, selecting all the White persons would be done using a `race = 1` operation.

In contrast, R would store this data as a factor. Consider the following.

```
sample <- data.frame(id = c(1:9),
                     race = c(1,1,2,3,1,2,4,3,1))
sample$race <- factor(x = sample$race,
                      levels = c(1:4),
                      labels = c("White","Black","Asian","Other"))

> sample
  id  race
1  1 White
2  2 White
3  3 Black
4  4 Asian
5  5 White
6  6 Black
7  7 Other
8  8 Asian
9  9 White
```

In this case, the variable `race` is now of class `factor`, and R uses character comparisons and operations against it. For instance, selecting all the White persons in this would be done using some kind of `race = "White"` operation.

Despite the fact that R uses character operations against factors, the data is not actually stored as a character variable. The structure of the factor is:

```
> dput(sample$race)
structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("White","Black", "Asian", "Other"), class = "factor")
```

This is consistent with the documentation for `factor`, which states:

> `factor` returns an object of class `"factor"` which has a set of integer
>   codes the length of x with a `"levels"` attribute of mode `character` and
>   unique `(!anyDuplicated(.))` entries. If argument `ordered` is true (or
>   `ordered()` is used) the result has class `c("ordered", "factor")`.

So, R does in fact store factors as numeric values, with attached labels. Doing this reduces the storage space required when storing many records which take a small amount of discrete values. However, despite the underlying values being numeric, R uses character operators when working with factors, rather than numeric ones.

Comment: I actually came across this question again 2 days ago and put it on my to do list to add a CW answer. So, you saved me some work ;-)